# How to drag and drop views in Android tablet app?

Tags: android

I want to show a dashboard like interface in my Android tablet app where the user can drag and drop listviews using touch. Is there a library that i can use to give d&d to my app?

Comment: what you have tried so far? have you referenced any tutorials/articles/example yet?

Answer (score 1):

For android 3.0 and up, which is usually in all Android tablets. You can use this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

You do not necessarily need a library to give the drag and drop functionality. It is already in Android 3.0 and up. If you want the code, the best way is to write it yourself as it will suit you to what you want. To learn about it, look at several examples and read them. It is pretty simple and acts much like OnTouchListener and MotionEvent.